# Application Installation Failed- Installation Failed with message null

Tags: android, android-studio, android-install-apk

I tried to build the APK file for my project. It created a file in the build folder. After that I am not able to test my app further as the new project after any changes is not getting installed in my device now. I tried most of the solutions given on the internet. The project is built successfully but it just doesn't get installed. The installation goes on forever. And then an error message pops up like the one given in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxjJN.png). It is a screenshot of the error message.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding and then running the app. It didn't worked. I deleted the build folder. It didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution. The app was not properly uninstalled. It was not showing in the app drawer but it was there when I opened the **Application Manager** from my phone's **Settings**. From there, I uninstalled the app and then reinstalled it from /android Studio and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run off *Instant Run* **Settings** -> **Build, Execturion, Depoyment** -> **Instant Run**, disable there.